# How to change the application name that will be displayed after install?

Tags: android

I wanted to change my applications name. I changed it in the manifest.xml file in application tag using android:label="required app name". My application's apk file has been renamed but when i install the app, the old name appears below the app icon. How to change that name?

Comment: Did you uninstall and reinstall the app? Or, did you reboot the device? Home screens do not detect the fact that you changed some resource, and so it may take a bit more work to get them to reload.

Comment: i reinstalled the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `android:label` of your [launcher activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#launching-activity) takes precedence over any `android:label` set on your `<application>` tag. Make sure your launch activity either does not have an `android:label` or it is set to the appropriate string.

Comment: I added the same android:label to my launcher activity. Still the name wont change after a reinstall.

Comment: I assume you've already tried doing things like restarting your device? It may be that your app is working fine but the launcher you are using is caching the name inappropriately.

Comment: I changed app name in resources in strings.xml and i also used USB debugger to run the app on my phone instead of installing just the apk file. I dont which one of these did the work but the app name got changed. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you got it working. If this helped you solve your problem, please accept the answer. Thanks and good luck!